# Jmeter remote testing: Master machine starts but freezes

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, distributed-system, master-slave

I have followed along the below tutorial to setup a distributed testing environment for Jmeter:

https://www.perfmatrix.com/configuration-process-for-distributed-testing-in-jmeter-5-3/

I have managed to start the remote (slave machine) server and then to trigger the test from the master machine in NON-GUI mode.

But it doesn't want to finish the execution...what could be the reasons for this?

(I am using Jmeter version 5.4 on both machines, and they are in the same network. The master machine is Win OS and the slave machine is Mac OS)

**Details about the test**

When it comes to the Thread plan I am having a simple HTTP Sampler that makes a request to https://www.google.com (port 443) and no customized listener plugins in the Thread group, just a simple listener. I have no externalized data such as a CSV either.

In master jmeter.properties file I have only added an entry: 
*remote_hosts=[internal IP-address]*

I have also copied over the *.jks* file generated from the master to the bin folder of the slave machine.

I have first started the jmeter-server from the slave machine with the following command:
*sh ./jmeter-server Djava.rmi.server.hostname=[slave machine internal IP-address]*

Afterwards I have started the master jmeter in NON-GUI by following: 
*jmeter -n -t [UNC-path to jmx file] -r*

*If you need additional details, just let me know!*

Answer (score 1):

1. The referenced article contains several steps which are not required and some statements which are not true at all.
2. We cannot help you without seeing:

   - Your test plan, at least [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configuration
   - [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file from master
   - jmeter-server.log file from slave

The most common problems are:

- RMI ports are not open in the [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) so the master cannot communicate with the slave or vice versa
- Test plan uses a [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) which is not installed on the slave
- Test plan uses an external data file, i.e. CSV file used in the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and the file isn't present in the slave

More information:

- [Remote Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)

Comment: Thank you for the suggested articles. I will go through them to see what I have missed. I am assuming (but not sure ofcourse) that the issue is somehow related to permissions, i.e not being able to communicate because of restrictions on what ports you can configure. That is because, I just have a simple testplan and a simple request without externalized data and the jmeter versions are the same on both machines.